# Unreachable Code android

Tags: java, return

I get an Unreachable Code error at the DO IF statement below. I am guessing it is because the code is returning after each IF statement. I do not understand how to fix that issue or how to make the code snip work without the return; after each one. Please advise

```
public void onDiceDialogClick(View paramView) {
    if (paramView.getId() == R.id.dice_4)
        displayDiceResult(4);
    do {
        return;
        if (paramView.getId() == R.id.dice_6) {
            displayDiceResult(6);
            return;
        }
        if (paramView.getId() == R.id.dice_10) {
            displayDiceResult(10);
            return;
        }
        if (paramView.getId() == R.id.dice_20) {
            displayDiceResult(20);
            return;
        }
        if (paramView.getId() == R.id.planeswalker_dice) {
            this.mDiceMenu.dismiss();
            rollPlanechaseDice();
            return;
        }
    } while (paramView.getId() != R.id.coin);
    this.mDiceMenu.dismiss();
    flipCoin();
}
```

Comment: As @kkumar9844 pointed, I don't think you meant to have a `return` statement at the beginning of your `do-while` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `return` at the top of your `do-while` loop.

Nothing after that statement can ever be executed, thus it's unreachable.

Comment: While this *is* the answer, SO isn't "Jeopardy" - your answer shouldn't be phrased in the form of a question ;)